# boost asio connect() succeeds but read() fails with `Error (end of file)`

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I have the below code using Boost Asio to connect and read from a TCP socket.

`connect()` succeeds but on the call to `read()` I get 'Error (end of file)'.

Is there a problem with the code, or it might be the network setup?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct Conn
{
   Conn(){}

   void start()
   {
      boost::system::error_code ec;

      // Not the real IP and port
      socket_.connect( tcp::endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234 ), ec);
      if(ec)
      { 
          // Log error
      }
      else
      {
          listen();
      }
   }

   void listen()
   {
       std::vector<char> buffer;
       const int bytes_to_read = 20;
       buffer.resize(bytes_to_read);

       boost::system::error_code ec;
       const size_t n = boost::asio::read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), ec);
       if(ec)
       { 
           // Fails with 'Error (end of file)'
       }
   }

   tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

Comment: calling it `listen` is quite confusing. `listen`-ing is associated with acceptor sockets ("server" sockets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOF is signaled when the peer shutdown the sending side. It's not an error, unless of course you don't expect it to happen.

Just deal with partial success if your application expects it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/347a2361cf3353bb)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct Conn {
    Conn() = default;

    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

    void start() {
        error_code ec;
        socket_.connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234),
                        ec);
        if (ec) {
            // Log error
        } else {
            do_read();
        }
    }

    void do_read() {
        std::vector<char> buffer(20);

        error_code   ec;
        const size_t n = boost::asio::read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), ec);
        std::cout << "Received " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

        if (!ec.failed() || (n && ec == asio::error::eof)) { // success or partial success
            //
        }
    }

    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket      socket_{ioc};
};

int main() {
    Conn c;
    c.start();
}
```

Build

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
```

Test

```
(printf 'short message' | nc -w 1 -l -p 1234& sleep .5; ./a.out; wait)
Received 13 bytes (End of file)
(printf 'longer message over 20 chars' | nc -w 1 -l -p 1234& sleep .5; ./a.out; wait)
Received 20 bytes (Success)
```

Comment: Hi, my understanding is `read()` will block until 20 bytes are available to read. I attempt to read, the code doesn't block, it just returns an error. So to me, this shouldn't be happening? Or is this a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: It means that the client shutsdown the connection BEFORE 20 bytes are received, as my live examples demonstrate. Note that you **also** get the partial read (13 bytes in my example)